# How to change a part of layout with a button without using tabHost?

Tags: android, android-layout

The main layout of my program has three sections: top, mid and the bottom. By clicking buttons, I want the only mid-section of the screen change with other two parts remained the same. So it's similar with tab layout but without using tabHost I would like to change mid-section screen by imageview.

I tried to start a new activity contained in a view, but failed. Also tried to load entirely new layout containing all three sections, but also failed due to memory issues.

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to handle this requirement will be to use fragments. It can be used by including the compatibility library of android which is jar include in the android sdk folder.
[Here is a tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/).

If it is something simple like switch between simple views. You can also use a view flipper.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple

**First Method:**

```
step 1: design common xml layout for top,mid,bottom.

step 2: every Activity you have to inflate or change the mid part .

    setContentView(R.layout.common_xml_layout);
        mid= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mid_view);
        mid.removeAllViews();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Your_Inflate_Xml, null);
        mid.addView(v);
```

In First Method you have to take care of finish the Activities.

**Second Method :**

```
step 1: design common xml layout for top,mid,bottom.

step 2: Extends your MainActivity 


Your MainActivity-->public class MainActivity extends Activity 

Your subActivities-->public class subActivity extends MainActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use fragments to achieve this.
Use android.app.Fragment for v11 or later and use the compatibility library Fragment for versions < 11.

Here is a tutorial on how fragments could be used in a modified version of Notepad app
[Honeypad Tutorial](http://android-codelabs.appspot.com/resources/tutorials/honeypad/index.html)